# Echoing array values

Tags: php, arrays

This is a common question, but I've not been able use solutions to what I'm working on.  I'm having trouble understanding how echoing the values in an array works, any help is appreciated.  The following code;

```
$sql = 'someQuery';
$dev='someString';
$device = $client->executeSQLQuery(array("sql"=>$sql));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($device);
echo "</pre>";
```

Will yield the following output;

```
stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [row] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => someString
                            [userid] => user1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => someString
                            [userid] => user2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is very easy to understand.  I also understand that in order to echo the contents of this output I need to use a foreach loop.  I'm trying to echo each instance of userid (which occurs twice in the output).

```
foreach($device as $first)  
        {
        if( is_array($first->row) )
                {
                $userid = $first->userid;
                foreach($userid as $second)
                        {
                        echo "<b>UserID</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $device->return->row->userid . $
                        }
                }
        }
```

So, this does not work and likely because I didn't learn it the proper way the first time.  In this case, as I understand it, the if statement doesn't even need to be there because we don't need to evaluate if the content is an array (it's not).  Can someone explain the logic of how to go through the array and echo each instance of the object userid?

Comment: try using this: `foreach($device->return->row as $info){ echo $info->userid; }`

Comment: you're not understanding output, `$device` is not an array, it is object

Comment: You are trying to loop through `$device`, but it is not an array, it is an `Object`. Unless the object implements the PHP ArrayAccess interface, you cannot loop through it. What do you mean it doesn't work? are you getting an error, or are you not getting the right output?

Comment: Yes, clearly I need to understand this better.  @DerekPollard 's solution did trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention on the print_r output. `$device` is stdClass not a array, it has a property called `return` which also is a stdClass. Once again has a property called `row` this property is a array.

So as @derek-pollard said,  you need to do, something like this:

```
foreach($device->return->row as $info) { 
    echo "<b>UserID</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $info->userid;
    echo "<b>UserName</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $info->name;
}
```

It'll work because `$device->return->row` will return the array of users. For beginners, the foreach will iterate once for each item (inside the array) and `$info` will have the content of the current item.

Finally it will print:

```
<b>UserID</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;user1
<b>UserName</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;someString
<b>UserID</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;user2
<b>UserName</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;someString
```

Comment: Thank you, Vinicius.  This is very helpful, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In your example `row` is an array of objects. `userid` is just an object's property which is assigned with primitive value. You can't iterate through such kind of properties:

```
foreach($device->return->row as $obj)  
{
    echo $obj->userid; // this gives 'userid' value
}
```

Your assumption will be reasonable if you would store some array in `userid` property